# UseEffect not updating react web site data when dispatch sent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I am creating a book recommendation site to practice the MERN stack however I have just implemented liking a blog but to see the number of likes after you have liked it you need to refresh the site.How do I fix this?

This is the blog component and at the bottom I have two buttons to dispatch liking the post and deleting it. Once delete is pressed it removes it from the page but the like doesn't work.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Card, CardContent, CardActionArea, CardMedia, Paper, Typography, Grid, Button} from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import FavoriteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite';
import { deleteBlog, likeBlog } from '../../../actions/blogs';

//Styles
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=>({
  root: {
    '& .MuiTextField-root': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
    media: {
      height: 190,
      width:160,
    },
    card: {
      margin: '5px',
      width: '70%'
    },
    cardContent: {
      margin: '0x',
    },
    actionArea:{
      width: 100,
    }
  }));

const Blog = ({blog, currentId}) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
    return ( 
            <Card className={classes.card}>
            <CardContent>
                      <Typography variant="h5">{blog.title}</Typography>
                    </CardContent>
             <Grid container>
              <Grid item className={classes.cardContent}>
                <CardMedia image={blog.selectedFile} title={blog.title} className={classes.media}/>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item className={classes.cardContent}>
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography variant="p">{blog.content}</Typography>
                  <br/>
                  <Typography variant="p">RATING: {blog.rating}/10</Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </Grid>
             </Grid>
             <CardContent align="right">
              <Button onClick={() => dispatch(deleteBlog(blog._id))}><DeleteIcon color="secondary"/></Button>
              <Button onClick={()=> dispatch(likeBlog(blog._id))}><FavoriteIcon color="primary"/>{blog.likes}</Button>
             </CardContent>
            </Card>
     );
}
 
export default Blog;
```

This is the app.js where the useEffect is:

```
//Imports
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
//Importing all components
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import pageNotFound from './components/404/404';
import Blogs from './components/Blogs/Blogs';
import Form from './components/Form/Form';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {getBlogs} from './actions/blogs';

function App() {
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(0);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getBlogs());
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
          <div className="Content">
          <Navbar/>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Home setCurrentId={setCurrentId} currentId={currentId}/>
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/create">
                <Form setCurrentId={setCurrentId} currentId={currentId}/>
              </Route>
              <Route component={pageNotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Here is the like blog actions:

```
export const likeBlog = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.likeBlog(id);
        dispatch({ type: LIKE, payload: id });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Here is the reducers:

```
import { FETCH_ALL, FETCH, CREATE, DELETE, LIKE} from '../constants/actionType';

//Checking for action type and responding
export default (blogs =[], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ALL:
            return action.payload;
        case FETCH:
            return action.payload;
        case CREATE:
            return [...blogs, action.payload];
        case DELETE:
            return blogs.filter((blog) => blog._id !== action.payload);
        case LIKE:
            return blogs.map((blog) => (blog._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : blog));
        default:
            return blogs;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code that defines the like functionality?

Comment: Like in which reducers, actions, the api i am kind of a noob in mern rn

Comment: the ``likeBlog`` action

Comment: @Josh I edited it is that what you needed?

Comment: Can you check if your likeBlog action is being called. If yes, then please share the reducer too

Comment: It is being called cause the likes data changes in the database but you need to refresh the site to see the change which shouldn't be the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dispatching just the `id` as the payload In the `likeBlog` action, `action.payload._id` in the reducer is `undefined` causing the callback passed to `map` to return the old blog object for every item in the `blogs` array (you're comparing `blog._id` with `undefined`).

You should dispatch the updated blog object as the payload instead.

```
dispatch({ type: LIKE, payload: id })
```

should be

```
dispatch({ type: LIKE, payload: data })
```

Comment: Ur a legend thanks for the help i love u so much